# PHP random generated number to show matching name and id corresponding to the random number

Tags: php

how to make something like a random lottery. Very simple, in the fact that it shouldn't be long code.

I just want a form that i user can click a radio button which equals 1 and enter their name. When they submit $min = 1(and stays at 1), $max = $max + 1.

Lets say 10 people select the radio button and hit the first submit button. $min = 1 meaning the lowest random number is 1. Then their name is put into an array along with a matching id corresponding to the number in the variable $max(if 5 people submitted, the $max would be 5, and their id would also be 5 as they submitted fifth.

So if 10 people submit , and then click another submit button below a random generated number will be made with a minimum of $min which is 1 and a maximum of $max (the last person to submit radio button).

if the random generated number was 7, then display the 7th person that submitted the radio button(because their id would match with the random number).

I have been learning php for 2 weeks so im not very good now, but my code goes like this...

```
<form action="POST" name="form">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="radio" name="1" value="1">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">

</form>
<?php

$min = "";
$max = "";

$person = array();

for($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
$max = $max + 1;

$person[$max] = $_POST["name"] . ;
$min = 1;
}

?>

<form action="POST" name="random">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<?php 
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && $_POST["name"] == "random"){
    $rand=------rand($min,$max);
    if(//TODO) {
       $person[$]
    }
}
?>
```

can someone explain how to make this work please?

Comment: 2 trains leave opposite stations at the same time ..

Comment: one is loaded with ducks the other turnips

Comment: Does ACME have a produce section too?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you store everything to a MySQL database a possible solution to retrieve a lottery winner would be:

```
$DB_winner = mysql_query("select name from participants_table_name");
while($win = mysql_fetch_array($DB_winner){
   $winners[] = $win['name'];
}

// and the winner is $the_winer:
$the_winner = $winners[rand(0, sizeof($winners)-1)];
```

Answer (score 0):

I was going to post a comment but it's busy with trains at the moment so...

You will need to learn and understanding the following for your task

1. Save the data using a file (json or csv up to you), or mysql if you want to further the project. See tutorials for any of this
2. Learn how `$_POST`, `isset`, `for`, `foreach` etc works and what they're used for
3. My advice is to ignore the above and start with absolute basics. Go through w3schools maybe. You're trying to build a palace when you're struggling with lego